# Can I recover a deleted folder in Divshot?

Tags: divshot

I stupidly deleted my entire "stylesheets" directory while un-cluttering my Navigator pane.  I tried using the "Recover" feature but it seems that it is file-specific and does not restore an complete project state.

Is there some way to restore the deleted folder (and files) or am I out of luck?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm very sorry to hear this happened to you! It's certainly possible that we have a backup of your stylesheets directory. Get in touch with support@divshot.com with your account information and we'll be happy to help.